# CSS layout problem

Tags: html, css, layout

Hi im new to css and iv been trying to position a link under a text box "forgot password" link. In firefox on windows its out of line with the edge of the text box. Can anyone give me any pointers. Below is what i was trying to use:

```
.resetPassword {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    style=top: 331px;
    style=left: 316px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
.resetPassword {

    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 331px;
    left: 316px;

}
```

`style=top` and `style=left` aren't CSS properties.

Answer (score 1):

use this css:

```
input
{
float:left;
}
.resetPassword
{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is this:

`style=top: 331px; style=left: 316px`?

Try without style=..:

`top: 331px; left: 316px`

You should know that position absolute is relative to the next parent element thats positioned absolute or relative.

Try to give your parent element a position: relative and position your link to the bottom of the container.

Greeting, MRu

Comment: i used this css and in linux firefox works fine but not windows firefox                                                                                                                                             font-style: italic;
 font-size: 80%;
 padding-left: 240px;
 position: relative;
 top: -5px;

Comment: I didnt mean you should use position relative to position your elements. Your link should stay absolute. But you could also try to give the parent container `position: absolute;` and the link your trying to move `position:absolute; bottom: 0; right: auto;` (or 0 or whatever you want)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using absolute position ?
Assuming you have this two elements:

```
<input type="password" class="password"/>
<span class="password-forgot">Forgot your password</span>
```

You can use something like this:

```
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password"></input><br />
Forgot yout password?
```

or

```
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" style="display:block"></input>
Forgot yout password?
```

If you really need a absolute position, remove the "style=" from you css, cause this is not a css property name, alias or anotherthing.